# не получается подключить и запустить статический sfml

Tags: c++, sfml

Есть такой простой код:

```cpp
#include "SFML/Graphics.hpp"

int main(void) {
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 800), "SFML Window.");

    sf::RectangleShape rectangle(sf::Vector2f(20, 20));

    rectangle.setPosition(10, 10);

    rectangle.setRotation(40);

    while(window.isOpen()) {
        sf::Event event;

        while(window.pollEvent(event)) {
            if(event.type == sf::Event::Closed) {
                window.close();
            }
        }

        window.clear(sf::Color::Black);

        window.draw(rectangle);

        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Скомпилировал исходники SFML через CMake.

В SFML\lib\ есть все библиотеки, а в SFML\include\ все include файлы, и в SFML\bin\ есть openal32.dll

Пытаюсь запустить программу так: `g++ test.cpp -o test.exe -std=c++11 -Wall -DSFML-STATIC -I SFML\include\ -L SFML\lib -lsfml-graphics-s -lsfml-window-s -lsfml-system-s -lopengl32 -lwinmm -lgdi32 -lfreetype`

Вывод:

```
<command-line>: warning: ISO C++11 requires whitespace after the macro name
c:/users/ione/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\IonE\AppData\Local\Temp\ccMBe0qT.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x83): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf6StringC1EPKcRKSt6locale'
c:/users/ione/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\IonE\AppData\Local\Temp\ccMBe0qT.o:test.cpp:(.text+0xa7): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf9VideoModeC1Ejjj'
c:/users/ione/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\IonE\AppData\Local\Temp\ccMBe0qT.o:test.cpp:(.text+0xeb): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf12RenderWindowC1ENS_9VideoModeERKNS_6StringEjRKNS_15ContextSettingsE'
c:/users/ione/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\IonE\AppData\Local\Temp\ccMBe0qT.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x13f): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf14RectangleShapeC1ERKNS_7Vector2IfEE'
c:/users/ione/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\IonE\AppData\Local\Temp\ccMBe0qT.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x163): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf13Transformable11setPositionEff'
c:/users/ione/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\IonE\AppData\Local\Temp\ccMBe0qT.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x17f): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf13Transformable11setRotationEf'
c:/users/ione/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\IonE\AppData\Local\Temp\ccMBe0qT.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x19e): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf6Window5closeEv'
c:/users/ione/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\IonE\AppData\Local\Temp\ccMBe0qT.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x1b5): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf10WindowBase9pollEventERNS_5EventE'
c:/users/ione/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\IonE\AppData\Local\Temp\ccMBe0qT.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x1c2): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf5Color5BlackE'
c:/users/ione/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\IonE\AppData\Local\Temp\ccMBe0qT.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x1d7): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf12RenderTarget5clearERKNS_5ColorE'
c:/users/ione/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\IonE\AppData\Local\Temp\ccMBe0qT.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x1e0): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf12RenderStates7DefaultE'
c:/users/ione/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\IonE\AppData\Local\Temp\ccMBe0qT.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x1f9): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf12RenderTarget4drawERKNS_8DrawableERKNS_12RenderStatesE'
c:/users/ione/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\IonE\AppData\Local\Temp\ccMBe0qT.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x20c): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf6Window7displayEv'
c:/users/ione/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\IonE\AppData\Local\Temp\ccMBe0qT.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x21f): undefined reference to `__imp__ZNK2sf10WindowBase6isOpenEv'
c:/users/ione/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\IonE\AppData\Local\Temp\ccMBe0qT.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x24b): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf12RenderWindowD1Ev'
c:/users/ione/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\IonE\AppData\Local\Temp\ccMBe0qT.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x2a7): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf12RenderWindowD1Ev'
c:/users/ione/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\IonE\AppData\Local\Temp\ccMBe0qT.o:test.cpp:(.text$_ZN2sf14RectangleShapeD1Ev[_ZN2sf14RectangleShapeD1Ev]+0xf): undefined reference to `__imp__ZTVN2sf14RectangleShapeE'
c:/users/ione/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\IonE\AppData\Local\Temp\ccMBe0qT.o:test.cpp:(.text$_ZN2sf14RectangleShapeD1Ev[_ZN2sf14RectangleShapeD1Ev]+0x21): undefined reference to `__imp__ZTVN2sf14RectangleShapeE'
c:/users/ione/gcc/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\IonE\AppData\Local\Temp\ccMBe0qT.o:test.cpp:(.text$_ZN2sf14RectangleShapeD1Ev[_ZN2sf14RectangleShapeD1Ev]+0x3b): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN2sf5ShapeD2Ev'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Как пофиксить?

Comment: `-DSFML_STATIC` - подчеркивание, а не дефис

Comment: Советую почитать про `pkg-config`. Руками указывать правильные флаги компилятора - это немного каменный век, если можно получить их из pkg-config. (Если поставить и компилятор, и sfml, и pkg-config из [msys2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/2752075), то оно все легко заработает из коробки).

Comment: @user7860670, спасибо большое, заработало!

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, почитаю что это, спасибо!